# Elegant way to store text file data in a dynamic array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, file, loops

I'm building a file text parser, with strings formatted in a certain way. They all end with a `\n` char.

I need to build an array of strings that contains every line. I want to make the most dynamic possible, with the least use of variables, so there won't be an initial size for the dynamic array, but it's going to be expanded with a `realloc`.

My problem is that I need to *stop whenever I read a certain 'stop' string from the file*, and I don't know exactly where to place this check, or how to do it in the most elegant way.
This is what I thought about:

```
char * temp = malloc(STRLEN * sizeof(char)); //temporary string
int i = 0, size = 1; //i=strArray pointer, size=strArray size
char ** strArray = malloc(size * sizeof(char*)); //array of strings
strArray[i] = (char *)malloc(STRLEN+1);
strcpy(temp ,strArray[i]);
while(strcmp(temp,"stop\n")!=0)
{
    fgets(temp,STRLEN,fp);
    strcpy(trArray[i],temp);
    i++;
    size++;
    trArray = realloc(trArray, size * sizeof(char*));
    trArray[i] = (char *)malloc(STRLEN+1);
}
```

My concerns with this algorithm are two:

1. I need to use a temporary `temp` string and then copying the content with `strcpy`
2. At the end of the while, I still have saved 'stop', which I don't want to, and allocated one more space.

Basically **my problem is that I don't know how to proper iterate this array.
What am I doing wrong, and what can I improve?**

Comment: Calling realloc at every single iteration of your loop is catastrophic, performance-wise.

Comment: @spectras Would you recommend to count the lines I'm going to insert into the array, and do a `calloc` just once, instead of doing `realloc` multiple times?

Comment: (1) `sizeof char` is always 1 by definition. (2) In the statement `strcpy (temp, strarray [i])` the pointer `strarray [0]` points to an uninitialized string; this is undefined behavior. You want to add a `fgets()` before this statement. (3) The normal pattern is to start with an array of some initial capacity, and when it fills up allocate some more capacity in chunks, not one by one. (4) The code believes that text lines never have more than `STRLEN` characters; good text editor don't make such assumptions. (5) You want to move the `fgets()` from the beginning to the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: @riciloma or change your reallocation to grow the array geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

As you read from file you can count size for your array and later don't use realloc at all. It can be done in such way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 1024

int get_size(void)
{
        int  nlines  = 0;
        char line[BUFFSIZE];
        FILE *fptr = fopen("t1.txt","r");

        while(fgets(line, BUFFSIZE, fptr) != NULL) {
            nlines++;
        }

        fclose(fptr);
        return nlines;
}

char **init(int size)
{
        int i;
        char **tmp;

        tmp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (size + 1)); //array of strings

        for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            tmp[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (BUFFSIZE + 1));
        tmp[i] = NULL;

        return tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
        char *temp;
        char **strArray;
        int pos = 0;
        int size = 0;
        ssize_t tmp_size;
        FILE *fptr;

        strArray = init(get_size());

        fptr = fopen("t1.txt", "r");
        do {
            if (getline(&temp, &tmp_size, fptr) == -1) {
                free(temp);
                break;
            }

            temp[strcspn(temp, "\n")] = 0;
            strcpy(strArray[pos++], temp);
        } while (strcmp(temp, "stop"));

        fclose(fptr);
        printf("%s\n", strArray[0]);
        printf("%s\n", strArray[1]);

        return 0;
}
```

my text file content is:

```
hello
world
stop
earth
bye
```

And output is:

```
hello
world
```

Of course is an example and it should optimized to your need (error checking, free memory etc) I leave it up to you.

Comment: It may be not elegant to read a file twice. Just increase the size of array as needed will be better? `new_size = old_size * 2` or `new_size = old_size * 3 / 2` .